# Setting AutoReverse true/false after Animation Starts

Tags: c#, wpf, animation, image-processing, c#-3.0

After Animation Starts in AnimationClock how we will control AutoReverse True/False in Int32Animation.

code Snippet.
Int32Animation FrameAnimation;
public void Load(){
   FrameAnimation = new Int32Animation();
   FrameAnimation.From = 1;
   FrameAnimation.To = 100;

AnimationClock FrameAnimationClock = FrameAnimation.CreateClock();
   ApplyAnimationClock(CurrentIndexProperty, FrameAnimationClock);

FrameAnimationClock.Controller.Begin();
}

public void AutoReverseButton_Click(object sender,EventArgs e){
 FrameAnimation.AutoReverse = true;
}

If i click AutoReverseButton it is not setting the AutoReverse.But no errors. Let me know how we will achieve this.

-Britto

Answer (score 0):

This is because Animations are freezable objects.  There is more information in the [MSDN Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms750509.aspx).

Once an animation is started, its properties cannot be changed, even in code-behind.  You will need to stop the animation in your event handler, set the AutoReverse property, and restart it.

Answer (score 0):

Store the current Values in local Variables then Set the AutoReverse true/false then Create the Clock then Assign back the stored values in the AnimationClock.